# How to anchor <li> number?

Tags: css, html

### Overview

I am trying to add footnotes to an HTML page. According to the W3C recommendation for [Common idioms without dedicated elements §4.12 Footnotes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#footnotes), the appearance of a footnote links to the footnote section and vice-versa. They provide an example of linking to a section with paragraph `<p>` elements with values inside.

Instead of a paragraph, I am using the `<footer>` element within the section to contain an ordered list `<ol>` element. For example:

```
<section id="section-2">
  <h2>Section 2 Title</h2>
  <p>Many paragraphs of information. But at least one sentence has a footnote reference, like this one.<sup><a id="r1" href="#fn1">1</a></sup>
  <footer id="section-2-footnote">
    <ol>
      <a id="fn1" href="#r1"><li>Although it's not a very informative footnote. But more information can be seen in the <a href="#appendix">appendix</a>.</li></a>
    <ol>
  </footer>
</section>
```

### Problem

In the example, the *entire* `<li>` element (**except** the number itself) is a part of the anchor. This becomes confusing if the footnote itself links to some other part of the document (e.g. an appendix, caption, table, etc.) as it is indistinguishable from the rest of the anchor.

### Desired outcome

What I would like to do is get the numbered value rendered by the `<li>` element to serve as a link back to the reference. For now, I only want to handle single instance references. Something similar to:

[1.](/q/#Overview) First

[2.](/q/#Overview) Second

[3.](/q/#Overview) And so on..

> Is there a way to anchor the number value of a `<li>` element?

Comment: On the EBooks StackExchange, I found https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/6690 asking the same. As of yet, no one answered the question correctly. Also, I'm not trying to get it to work against the [EPUB Standards](http://idpf.org/epub).

Comment: Not sure but might be less confusing to users to have small link at the end of each line.  Something like `<ol> <li>First [<a href="#ref1">ref</a>] </li> ...`

Comment: In your example, you have `<a href="r1">` in the ol, outside of any li, which confuses the browser. Did you mean something like `<li><a href="#r1">^</a>...`?

Comment: @MrLister I've updated the markup and removed the part about how Wikipedia approaches the problem (as it's a workaround and undesired result). My goal is to place the anchor on the number in the list, not on content _within_ the list item.

Comment: @ShooShoSha I hadn't understood that, sorry. In that case, what you are trying to do can't be done in that way. Put an <a> inside the <li> and don't use the <li>'s own numbering, but use CSS counters instead.